# Real-World Example for the Horizontal Spring-Block Oscillator

Tags: experimental-physics, harmonic-oscillator, spring

I am wondering whether there exists a spring that behaves like those shown in a multitude of physics textbooks, where a mass stretched/compressed to a certain point oscillates back and forth in some way. Is it even physically viable for a spring to behave that way when connected on one end to a solid, immovable entity, and on the other to a mass lying upon a low-friction surface? I have only seen springs that strictly compress or stretch, but not both, so the image of the spring block oscillator with both compression and stretching properties is baffling. Is there a real-world example of this, or a good explanation of why it cannot actually occur?

Comment: The harmonic oscillator is an idealization that works well for a number of systems. If you wanted to engineer a really good one (in terms of linearity and absence of secondary modes), you would probably go for an electrical implementation, rather than a mechanical one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are springs design to work well in both compression and tension, though they generally

1. cost a fair amount, and
2. will extend farther than they will compress.

But it's hard to set up the one-sided horizontal arrangement shown in books because of the springs tendency to buckle as well as the difficulty in removing friction from the *spring's* interaction with the surface. The two sided version is easy to realize on the bench (you just sum the spring constants), as is the vertical one-sided arrangement. Of course it take a little more math to show that the vertical problem is completely equivalent to the horizontal one.